# Install: can't stat '/tmp/tmp.emBnEh/terraform-provider-snowflake': No such file or directory

Tags: gitlab, terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Testing snowflake opensource terraform module, getting below error after few minutes. Any idea.?

https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake/master/download.sh | bash -s -- -b $HOME/.terraform.d/plugins
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  9367  100  9367    0     0  37318      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 37318
chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake info checking GitHub for latest tag
chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake info found version: 0.9.3 for v0.9.3/linux/amd64
install: can't stat '/tmp/tmp.emBnEh/terraform-provider-snowflake': No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[`download.sh`](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake/blob/25438578032e13a87ba9315e9326e85e60f41c04/download.sh#L45) uses the [`mktempdir` function](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake/blob/25438578032e13a87ba9315e9326e85e60f41c04/download.sh#L236-L240)

```
mktmpdir() {
  test -z "$TMPDIR" && TMPDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
  mkdir -p "${TMPDIR}"
  echo "${TMPDIR}"
}
```

Check on your system (it depends on your OS and OS version) what $TEMPDIR is set to, and if you have the right to write in it.

Answer (score 0):

$binexe doesn't include the tag on install.
[download.sh#L57](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake/blob/master/download.sh#L57)

please fix as below.

```
execute() {
...
  for binexe in "terraform-provider-snowflake_${TAG}" ; do
...
}
```